# PHPspreadsheet: How to to open a file in reading mode?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I don't want to put a password on a file or anything, all I want is to open the file in reading mode, and if the user wants to edit anything, he'll have to click on the yellow banner on top that says "enable editing"

I have tried [mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639823/1920003) line by line, didn't work

```
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword('secret');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSort(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);
```

Those options are great if one wants to disable editing for good, all I want to say is display a warning, the standard warning that you see when trying to edit an excel file.

Comment: Why not activate the directory write protection?

Comment: @Sundance_Raphael would that solve the problem? if so, how to do that?

Comment: For exemple you can use php chmod https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.chmod.php or you set the file per hand read only

Comment: @Sundance_Raphael issue solved, by mistake. The way the file is downloaded seems to trigger the protected view. I answered the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by mistake, I have no explanation on why my problem got solved, I wasn't planning on solving it, I was fixing the way the excel file gets downloaded and it solved the problem.

Previously, I used to open a new tab in Javascript, generate the excel and download it, I didn't like that, because what if the file is empty? I wanted a way to check if the file is empty from javascript before downloading the file.

So I did this

```
        fetch(url)
            .then(resp => resp.blob())
            .then(file => {
                if (file.size > 0) {
                    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    const a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.style.display = 'none';
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'filename.xlsx';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                } else {
                    $('#banner').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">This provider does not seem to have any data during the selected dates, if you believe there is an issue, please contact the developers</div>');
                }
            })
            .catch(() => $('#banner').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">This provider does not seem to have any data during the selected dates, if you believe there is an issue, please contact the developers</div>'));
```

It seems that getting the file from Javascript like that and rename it and then downloading it will make excel open the file in a protected view, for some reason.