# Php Excel disable cell ..set protected

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

How to use set protected in PHP excel?
I am using PHP excel and I want to know how to make a cell disable in the PHP excel.

I want to know how that can be done. 
Currently, I am using this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:V2')->getProtection()-setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protect the Excel file using PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639731/protect-the-excel-file-using-phpexcel)

Answer (score 0):

Any tips for protect :

```
//PROTECT THE CELL RANGE

$objSheet->protectCells('A1:B1', 'PHP');
// UNPROTECT THE CELL RANGE

$objSheet->getStyle('A2:B2')->getProtection()
->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
// PROTECT THE WORKSHEET SHEET

$objSheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
```